# Convert InputStream to MultipartFile when sending multipart/form-data request via Feign Client

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have a **@RestController** with one method that accepts multipart requests.

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
void create(@Valid @RequestPart("body") RequestDto request, HttpServletRequest servletRequest);
```

Then I go through all parts and store only references to files' InputStream as the main goal was not to store any files in memory (in form of any byte[]).

```
...
servletRequest.getParts().forEach(part -> {
    fileDto.setFileContent(part.getInputStream());
});
...
```

Then I would like to call another API of a system, that actualy stores the files. I'd like to use **@FeignClient** from **spring-cloud-starter-openfeign**.

I found some examples on the internet, but most of them use java.io.File or feign.form.FormData which creates a temp file (or stores the byte[] array). So I prepared the script below.

```
@FeignClient(name = "feignClient", url = "${api.url}", configuration = FeignConfig.class)
public interface ExternalSystemConnector {

    @PostMapping(value = "/v1/file", headers = "Content-Type=multipart/form-data", produces = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    void createFile(@RequestPart("body") AdditionalInfoDto requestDto,
                      @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file);

}
```

Then I would like to call the external system:

```
...
externalSystemConnector.createFile(additionalInfoDto, convertToMultiPartFile(fileDto.getInputStream()));
...
```

but I have no idea how to convert **InputStream** to the **MultipartFile** in the **convertToMultiPartFile** method. The **MultipartFile** interface also has **getSize** / **getBytes** methods where I do not know the size as I hold only reference to an InputStream.

Does anyone know, how I could achieve that? Or is there any better solution to that? The main condition is to use FeignClient and do not store the file's content in the memory and just stream it to the external system.

Comment: I found out during debug, that feing is internally using byte[] and ByteOutputstream, so it's not possible to just stream it. I went back to WebClient.